# I am confused. How can I apply CSS in appropriate way for this?

Tags: css

Story short I have widgets sidebar. I style it like this:

```
.widgets ul {padding: 10px}
```

Now one of the ULs inside widgets I want to avoid padding from it, but keeping all other ULs use default padding of 10px.

So i tried to give class to children UL which I want no padding on like this

```
.tabs {padding:0}
```

I tried ul.tabs, and .widgets ul.tabs nothing seems to take effect. It still receives padding 10px. And I can't afford to do custom padding for every UL inside the widgets.

Can you please tell me what I am missing ?

The html is pretty basic.

```
<ul class="widgets">

     <li><h2>Widget title 1</h2>
          <ul>
          ....my widget content
          </ul>
     </li>

     <li><h2>Custom widget 1</h2>
          <ul class="tabs">
          ...this one I want to have padding:0..
          </ul>
     </li>

</ul>
```

Thats the html basic framework. I set padding:10px to any ul in PARENT widgets ul but I want specific custom widget to have its own custom styles, I can't do it :( in this case ul class=tabs

Comment: Please post your html code, too.

Comment: `ul.tabs` works fine for me. Maybe you are confusing padding with something else? Try adding a background colour to your `ul` and you'll notice the difference.

Comment: Inspect Element or Firebug can help. See where the padding is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "C" in CSS stands for "cascading". [Learn about the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) and you will see that your second rule is less specific than the first, so the first wins.
In general, the rule with more class selectors wins, and #ids trump most stuff.

To answer your question, adding specificity will do it.

```
.widgets ul.tabs {padding:0}
```

(assuming the .tabs is indeed on the ul like you said.)

Comment: Read the question carefully: the OP has already tried what you suggested.

Comment: granted, it could've been worded in nicer terms, but the answer is correct.  don't think it deserves to be voted down.  +1

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. I found it in my html element and dman solution worked. I apologize for that, )

Comment: Sorry about the downvote then, I'll remove it if you edit your answer. (It's too late to unvote now)

Comment: Sorry if you think it could have been worded better :-) I genuinely like letting people know that there are formal rules to the css cascade, because so many folk (myself included) spent ages with trial & error and guesswork in that field, adding selectors until one worked.
So a link to the spec can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

A more specific CSS selector should override a less specific one.  So your experiment with using `.widgets ul.tabs` should work.  Is it possible that when you tested that, your browser had cached an earlier version, or some such?

Here's my sample HTML page.  First I tried it the way you had it; it didn't work (as it shouldn't).  Then I changed it to what is here, and it worked (in Firefox).

```
<html>
<style>
.widgets ul {padding: 10px}
.widgets ul.tabs {padding:0}
</style>
<ul class="widgets">

<li><h2>Widget title 1</h2>
<ul>
....my widget content
</ul>
</li>

<li><h2>Custom widget 1</h2>
<ul class="tabs">
...this one I want to have padding:0..
</ul>
</li>

</ul>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay I think i will have to revise again. Cause I tested this once and it didn't work thats why i asked. But i see in the fiddle example, it works fine.. weird

Comment: I definitely sometimes run into issues where CSS is cached, especially if it's an external stylesheet.  Maybe that's what happened?

Comment: It works fine now..thanks, I think this specification works, but it just didnt work for me the first time

Answer (score 0):

example of what dman is talking about, with your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/8WRam/

( i think you might have missed the 's' in `.widgets` )